Pullback of riemannian volume form multiplied by a function
I am trying to make sure this probably elementary calculation is correct. Suppose I have a Riemannian manifold $\mathcal{M}$ with metric $g_\mathcal{M}$, if it helps we can assume $\mathcal{M}$ is compact. Suppose we have a function $f : C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M}) \to \mathbb{R}$ we define the form $\omega = f \mu_\mathcal{M}$ where $\mu_\mathcal{M}$ is the volume form.
Suppose I have another riemannian manifold $\mathcal{N}$ with its metric $g_\mathcal{N}$ and volume form $\mu_\mathcal{N}$. Suppose $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ are diffeomorphic, via a map $F : \mathcal{N} \to \mathcal{M}$. I want to calculate the pullback of $\omega$.
I did this calculation few times
$$
F^*\omega = F^*(f\mu_{\mathcal{M}}) = (F^*f)(F^* \mu_\mathcal{M}) = (F^*f)(F^*\sqrt{|g_\mathcal{M}|} F^*dx_\mathcal{M}) = (F^*f)(\sqrt{|F^*g_\mathcal{M}|}) |DF| dx_\mathcal{N} = (F^*f)\sqrt{\frac{|F^*g_\mathcal{M}|}{|g_\mathcal{N}|}} |DF| \sqrt{|g_\mathcal{N}|} dx_\mathcal{N} = (F^*f)\sqrt{\frac{|F^*g_\mathcal{M}|}{|g_\mathcal{N}|}} |DF| \mu_\mathcal{N}
$$
Are the calculations above correct? Notice in the above $|g_\mathcal{N}|, |g_\mathcal{M}|$ are the determiniants of the Riemannian tensor, $DF$ is the Jacobian of the coordinate transformation $F$ and $dx_{\mathcal{M}}$ and $dx_\mathcal{N}$ are the forms with the coordinates charts for $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ respectively.

Parts of this computation only work locally right? For example what is $dx_M$ without choosing coordinates?

Well I called it $\mu_M$. When you include the determinant of the metric tensor. But I am assuming orthnormal frames.

You explicitly write $dx_M$ on the second line?

I am not sure I understand. What I did was $F^*dx_M = |DF| dx_N$, is this what you mean? Is this the bit you say coordinate dependent? I suppose this answer your question because differential forms are defined locally per point?

I am just wondering if you are looking for a local expression of the pullback because it seems like that is what you are doing

Oh, yes, locally. And I just wonder if my calculation was done right.

If $F^g_M$ is the pullback of $g_M$ as a 2 tensor, then your calculation is incorrect. $F^ \sqrt{|g_M|} \neq \sqrt{ |F^*g_M|}$.

What should it be then?

It seems to me that @ArcticChar means that $\sqrt{\lvert g_M\rvert}$ is a function on the manifold, and pulling it back should be $\sqrt{\lvert g_M\rvert}\circ F$. Note that this can be different than $$\sqrt{\lvert F^*g_M \rvert}p= \sqrt{\lvert g_M\left(dF _ , dF _\right) \rvert}{F(p)}$$

@NG_ fair point.I will correct it.
